# 2D Rotation Orientation

Tags: graphics, computer-vision

I'm trying to make sense of all the ways I can use the Rotation matrix (sorry for unreadability):
R(x) = [ cos(x) -sin(x) ; sin(x) cos(x) ]

There are two types of coordinate systems (CS) that you can have:
CS1 --> positive x-axis going right and positive y-axis going up which is apparently the standard orientation people use.
CS2 --> positive x-axis going right and positive y-axis going down.

What I'm confused with is the sign of angle x when plugged into R(x). Depending on the sign of the numerical, the angle either makes a counter-clockwise or clockwise rotation (on an arbitrary vector) but for which CS orientation and how would the other orientation behave?

Also, if you could explain a bit more than what wikipedia has on alibi and alias transformations, that would be great. Which would be best to think of rotations in? If I think in the alias approach, would I have to use the opposite sign for angle x.
This is what I'm referring to:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Ambiguities

Thanks!

Would this be right...

Making use of R(x).

The vector undergoes a counter clockwise rotation of 'x' in CS1 (alibi). This relates to a clockwise rotation of CS1 of an angle 'x' (with the vector now having new coordinates). If x is negative then counter-clockwise becomes clockwise (alibi) and clockwise becomes counter-clockwise (alias)

If we were to use CS2...the above can be taken but with again swapping counter-clockwise with clockwise and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

In standard cartesian coordinates (what you've called "CS1") that matrix will cause a *counter clockwise* rotation to the *vector* (i.e. "alibi")

In the inverted Y axis case it'll be clockwise.

Comment: Sticking with CS1, if I switch to an alias approach, would I be required to swap the sign of angle x to make the same counter-clockwise rotation of the vector?

Comment: @Khaled I've actually not come across those terms before, but if you rotate the coordinate system instead of the vector, then yes, its rotation needs to be in the opposite direction.